# when trying to install the ros jade packages it doesn't show up the file or directory

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-ros-tutorials
> ```

I used

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-<jade>-ros-tutorials
```

it shows

```
bash: jade : No such file or directory
```

Could anyone please help me out in installation process.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221535/when-trying-to-install-the-ros-jade-packages-it-doesn%27t-show-up-the-file-or-directory/) by [rgsara](https://answers.ros.org/users/25179/rgsara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The angle brackets normally indicate that they should be replace with the name of the distro, so the correct command is:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-ros-tutorials
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1